# Bold line number suddenly started algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmic

I am currently facing some problem regarding bold numbering in algorithmic package

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Mining Three Node Root from Summary Graph}\label{algo_disjdecomp}

 \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input:} \\
 \hspace*{1.5cm}${\cal S_G}$:Co-expression Network\\
 \hspace*{1.5cm}${\gamma}$:Gamma Value of a Module\\
 \hspace*{1.5cm}${d}$:frequency threshold for the graph\\
 \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Output:} \\
 \hspace*{1.5cm}$\cal{R}$: Set of three node root\\


\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {FindRoot}{${\cal S_G}$,${\gamma}$,${d}$}
\State $\cal R = \emptyset            $~~~~~~~$\triangleright$Set of three node root  
\State $\cal M_X =\emptyset         $~~~~~~~$\triangleright$Empty Matrix for edge count
 \State $\cal M_F =\emptyset$~~~~~~~$\triangleright$Empty Matrix for frequent edge with count
\State $V$=$getVertices(\cal G)$~~~~~~~$\triangleright$Set of Vertices in $\cal G$
\State  \bf{for each} $G_i  \in \cal S_G $  :
\State \hspace*{1 cm} \bf{for each} $e_k\in  G_i$ :
\State \hspace*{1.5 cm} {\bf if} $e_k \notin \cal M_X$:
\State \hspace*{2 cm} {\bf Add} $e_k \hspace*{.25 cm} in \hspace*{.25 cm} \cal M_X$ 
\State \hspace*{2 cm} {\bf Set} $C_k$ to 1
\State \hspace*{1.5 cm}{\bf elseif}
\State \hspace*{2 cm}{\bf Increment }  $C_i$
\State \hspace*{1.5 cm}{\bf end elseif}
\State \hspace*{1 cm}{\bf end for}
\State {\bf end for}
\State {\bf for each} $e_i \in  \cal M_X$ :
\State\hspace*{1 cm} {\bf if} $C_i$ $>$ ${d}$:
\State\hspace*{1.5 cm}{\bf Add} in ${\cal M_X}$
\State\hspace*{1 cm}{\bf end if}
\State {\bf end for}
\State {\bf for each} $e_i\in \cal M_F$:
\State\hspace*{1 cm}{\bf for each} $G_i \in \cal S_G$ :
\State\hspace*{1.5 cm} {\bf Fill} $A_i$ of ${\cal M_F}$:~~~~~~~$\triangleright$ Attribute for every edge $e_i$
\State\hspace*{1 cm}{\bf end for}
\State {\bf end for}
\State {\bf for each} $e_i\in \cal M_F$:
\State \hspace*{1 cm} {\bf for each} $e_j\in \cal M_F$:
\State \hspace*{1.5 cm} {\bf if} $e_i$ and $e_j$ connected and $|  A_i \cap A_j |$ $>$ ${d}$
\State \hspace*{2 cm}{\bf Add} $e_i \cap e_j$ to \cal R
\State \hspace*{1.5 cm}{\bf end if}
\State \hspace*{1 cm}{\bf end for }
\State {\bf end for }

\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

output :
 [image]

Comment: It's `{\bf something}`, **not** `\bf{something}`... and BTW, it's deprecated since ever, you should use `\textbf{something}`. Your `\bf{for each}` is spilling boldness all around...

Comment: You have a non-grouped `\bf` which sets the font for everything following it. An updated version of your code that is far easier to read and uses the functionality provided by [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) is available in [this paste](https://pastebin.com/LafQUGxh).